# Adding layout that contains 2 button under a listview in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using a listview widget in my android app, I would like to add two buttons below it in a fixed position (You can scroll the list but the two buttons must always appear below it). Something like this:

```
 ------------ 
|            |
|   List     |
|            |
|            |
 ------------ 
| But1  But2 |
 ------------
```

In the android xml file graphical view everything looks OK. However, when I try to run the app the list-view appears but the buttons do not. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="411dp" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/darkbg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="@string/delete_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butOpen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="@string/open_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get it to work?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Code (after update - nothing changed):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLinearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/darkbg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="@string/delete_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butOpen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="@string/open_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can  use RelativeLayout.

Comment: Tried that didn't work

Comment: Can you post your updated code with layout screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Try to give weight to listview

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

Your ListView will be like:

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Are you using RelativeLayout as root layout ??

Comment: No Im not using RelativeLayout as root layout

Comment: Have you tried it on the code which was before updating your code to relativelayout?

Comment: yes, I tired it on both and I still get the same results (For the record - I am using a listview in a ListFragment class if that helps - thats why on tablet it only takes half screen)

Answer (score -1):

Put weight 9 or 8 in scrollview(enclose listview in scrollview) , then put weight 1 or 2 in Linearlayout containing buttons and don't change to relative layout.
Also put height = 0dp in both.

Comment: I still get the same result

Comment: Edited the answer,check it.